# How to get movie/tv show title from Netflix URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, netflix

I am working on a chrome extension that tracks extracts movie/tv show titles that the user has watched from the browser history. I am able to get titles from primevideo, disneyplus. But Netflix doesn't show any titles. Is there a way of getting titles using the id found in Netflix URLs? For eg: https://www.netflix.com/browse?jbv=80100172&jbp=1&jbr=2, here ID - 80100172 refers to "Dark" web series.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "Netflix doesn't show any titles"? It clearly shows titles in the page.   You can also extract it directly from the response from that URL (e.g. `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` and then use DOMParser or even a simple regexp).

Comment: I meant that in historyItem from chrome history, historyItem.title is just netflix.

Comment: I see. You'll need to make the network request as I suggested.

Comment: I tried XMLHttpRequest but it's getting blocked by CORS policy. Is there a way to get the movie title using movie id without scraping?

Comment: There's no other way. Sounds like you didn't add the URL to extension's permissions, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found, they use "aria-label" or title in some way in div 'billboard-title' with img. It can help you

Comment: or in the player there is a <h4>6 for example with film Breakfast Club: <h4 class="ellipsize-text">The Breakfast Club</h4>

Comment: Yeah, the class="ellipsize-text" has the title but when I use fetch or XMLHttpRequest, I get HTML of the page just before the player is loaded. This HTML misses the element, <div class="nf-kb-nav-wrapper> that contains the player.

Comment: I got the title by accessing HTML DOM of the active tab for which I used setTimeOut(), so that the player is loaded. Thanks for helping me out.